# It doesn't display the data, it only shows never-ending loop

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm getting a never-ending loop. What did I do wrong in this code? Thank you so much for helping me out.

```
void viewStudents()
{
    student *current = head;
    do
    {
        if(current == NULL)
            cout<<"Nothing here."<<endl;
        else
        {
        cout<<"Student Name: "<<current->name<<endl;
        cout<<"Student's ID Number: "<<current->studentNum<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Degree: "<<current->studentDeg<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Year Level: "<<current->studentYearLvl<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Contact Number: "<<current->studentCont<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Email: "<<current->studentEmail<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        current = head->next;
        }
    }
    while(current != NULL);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger yet, if not the real answer here is: learn how to use a debugger. This is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your programs one line at a time, inspect all variables and their values as they change, and analyze your programs' logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find the bug in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep setting `current` to `head->next`.
What you want is to set `current` to `current->next`

```
current = current->next;
```